# Should the precompiled header and source file be removed from the HEADERS and SOURCES section in the .pro file?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qmake, precompiled-headers

I have a precompiled header and source file in my project, but they are also added to the HEADER and SOURCES section of the .pro file:

```
SOURCES += stdafx.cpp
HEADERS += stdafx.h
PRECOMPILED_SOURCE = stdafx.cpp
PRECOMPILED_HEADER = stdafx.h
```

I never gave this much thought but now I'm wondering if this is correct. Should I remove them from the HEADERS and SOURCES section?

Comment: Generate the makefile using either one, diff them, and see how and if it matters.

Comment: @KubaOber Great idea. There are some differences, here's the diff at http://pastebin.com/8HYJKZg7. I haven't examined it closely yet to see if they're significant.